# How to play .mp3 files in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin, mp3, vaadin14

I want to play .mp3 files in Vaadin 14. This is my audio player.

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;

@Tag("audio")
public class AudioPlayer  extends Component {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AudioPlayer(){
        getElement().setAttribute("controls",true);

    }

    public  void setSource(String path){
        getElement().setProperty("src",path);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
player.setSource("music/my music file.mp3");
add(player);
```

But when I try to play .mp3 files, nothing happens. What have I missed?
Do I need to convert .mp3 files to .wav before? How can I do that just temporary.
I'm not planning to save any .wav files on the computer, because I already have .mp3 files stored.

Comment: what do you mean "nothing happens"? does your code run into an exception? does it terminate? is it frozen? does it find the music file? ...

Comment: You display the control, but did you add any listener on each action run from those control ? I can't see anything in your code about playing the music.

Comment: @Stultuske My code does not run into an exception. I pressing the white triangle, and no sound appear.

Comment: @BenjaminD The code `extends` from the class `Component`

Comment: @DanielMårtensson yes, ok, but does your code do anything? that is what Benjamin asked. is there a listener attached that 'll actually trigger your code to play the mp3 file(s)?

Comment: Is your mp3 file in the correct location? Can you open it in the browser?

Comment: @ErikLumme Hi My mp3 files can be located at https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Learn-French/tree/main/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/languages/French%20Audio

Comment: @ErikLumme Updated https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Learn-French/tree/main/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work, I just create [a PR to the Vaadin cookbook](https://github.com/vaadin/cookbook/pull/145) with a recipe for this.

Note that the browser needs to be able to access the audio file through that same path. If you set the `src` to `audio/mysong.mp3`, then you should be able to open it in the browser also as e.g. `localhost:8080/audio/mysong.mp3` (or the equivalent URL for your setup).

Take a look at [the ways of importing in Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing.html) to see where to put your file, in particular the *Resource Cheat Sheet* for static files.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure why your files don't work on the first try, but I could reproduce it in your project, also with my own mp3 files. You can see an error 416 in the console, something to do with a mismatch in the range of bytes requested.

I found a workaround that you could try (you might want to move your audio to just `src/main/resources` for this, and/or update the `AudioPlayer` to accept an `AbstractStreamResource`):

```
if(!reverseTranslation.getValue()) {
    frenchSentence.setValue(sentenceInFrench);
    String audioPath = "/META-INF/resources/audio/" + sentenceInFrench + ".mp3";
    
    AbstractStreamResource resource =
            new StreamResource(sentenceInFrench, () -> getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioPath));
    player.getElement().setAttribute("src", resource);
}
```

Comment: I can listen do these `.mp3` songs from `localhost:8080/audio/myMp3File.mp3` But in vaadin, no

Comment: Ok! Now it works 50%. First if I want to listen to `http://localhost:8080/audio/Un peu.mp3`, then I must go to my web browser and enter the URL `http://localhost:8080/audio/Un peu.mp3` manually. Then I can listen to `http://localhost:8080/audio/Un peu.mp3` from the media player in Vaadin. This must be a bug? Right?

Comment: Not sure what the cause of the issue is, you're getting a 416 error, for which I found some related questions on the internet, but not quite matching your case. Anyway, I updated my answer with a workaround.

Comment: One more question. Do I really need to have the files in `META-INF`? Can't I just save them in the project folder?

Comment: With this approach, you can have them anywhere, as long as they are on the classpath.

Comment: Solved it! https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Memorize-Sentences/blob/1cc6fba1524d4dce4feec3f1521d5d819ce2a99e/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/views/TrainView.java#L120